# Add a custom property/attribute to an existing control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to add a custom property to an existing control so that I can bind its value (mvvm)?

For example, I want to add a property as `DepartmentId` to a `Label`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a custom control extending `Label` while registering a custom bindable property - or create [attached properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties/).

**For e.g.,** create a custom attached property as following:

```
public class Ex
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DepartmentIdProperty = 
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached("DepartmentId", typeof(int), typeof(Ex), defaultValue: -1);

    public static int GetDepartmentId(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (int)view.GetValue(DepartmentIdProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDepartmentId(BindableObject view, int value)
    {
        view.SetValue(DepartmentIdProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Sample usage in `Label` would look like:

```
<Label x:Name="testLabel" local:Ex.DepartmentId="34" .. />
```

Or,

```
<Label x:Name="testLabel" local:Ex.DepartmentId="{Binding DeptId}" .. />
```

You can access this value using accessor methods defined:

```
var assignedId = Ex.GetDepartmentId(testLabel);
```